# WARNING: File path includes directory that doesn't exist

Tags: context, context-mkiv, svg, inkscape

## Version Information

### ConTeXt

```
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 0.63
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file:
/opt/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2016.07.18 16:46
```

### Inkscape

```
Inkscape 0.92pre1 unknown (Jul 30 2016)
```

I'm not sure if [this version](https://launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/+archive/ubuntu/trunk) of Inkscape is at fault.

## Minimum Working Example

### ConTeXt Code (./test.tex)

```
\setupexternalfigures[
  order={svg,pdf,png},
  location={local,default,global},
  directory={images},
  frameoffset=.5em,
  maxwidth=\makeupwidth,
  width=\makeupwidth,
]

\starttext
    \placefigure{}{\externalfigure[images/drawing.svg]}
\stoptext
```

### SVG File (./images/drawing.svg)

Any SVG file will do.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   id="svg8"
   version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 210 297"
   height="297mm"
   width="210mm">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     id="layer1">
    <rect
       y="8.2261906"
       x="12.851191"
       height="137.58333"
       width="178.40475"
       id="rect4231"
       style="color:#000000;display:inline;overflow:visible;visibility:visible;fill:#ffd5d5;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;marker:none;enable-background:accumulate"
/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

## Error Message

Running `context test.tex` produces:

```
... logging ...
** (inkscape:19807): WARNING **: File path
"--export-pdf=/home/username/temp/images/m_k_i_v_drawing.svg.pdf"
includes directory that doesn't exist.
... more logging ...
```

## Work Around

It is possible to avoid the error and produce the expected output by first converting the images from SVG to PDF:

```
$ cd images
$ inkscape -z drawing.svg \
--export-pdf=/home/username/temp/images/m_k_i_v_drawing.svg.pdf
```

Then:

```
$ cd ..
$ context test.tex
```

No errors.

## Question

Any ideas how to fix, without manually converting each file first?

Comment: Crosspost from the ConTeXt mailing list: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2016/086346.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To debug what is happening, run with:

```
context --trackers=graphics.conversion test.tex
```

The console output shows:

```
...
graphics        > inclusion > checking conversion of 'images/drawing.svg', fullname 'images/drawing.svg', old format 'svg', new format 'pdf', conversion 'default', resolution 'default', arguments ''
graphics        > inclusion > converting 'images/drawing.svg' ('images/drawing.svg') from 'svg' to 'pdf'
graphics        > inclusion > running command: inkscape "/tmp/images/drawing.svg" --export-dpi=600 -A --export-pdf="/tmp/images/m_k_i_v_drawing.svg.pdf"

** (inkscape:7970): WARNING **: File path "--export-pdf=/tmp/images/m_k_i_v_drawing.svg.pdf" includes directory that doesn't exist.

graphics        > inclusion > file 'images/drawing.svg' is bugged
...
```

Thus, the command that is being run is:

```
inkscape "/tmp/images/drawing.svg" --export-dpi=600 -A --export-pdf="/tmp/images/m_k_i_v_drawing.svg.pdf"
```

Running this command through the command line also gives the same error message. 
Based on [this stackexchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725801/converting-svg-to-png-with-inkscape-command-line-failing), it appears that `-A` and `--export-pdf` specify the same option. So, when `inkscape -A --export-pdf="..."` is used, `inkscape` thinks that `--export-pdf="..."` is the name of the file. So, `inkscape` should be called without the `-A` argument.

To do so, add the following at the top of your `.tex` file:

```
\startluacode
 figures.programs.inkscape = {
     command  = "inkscape",
     pdfargument = [[
         "%oldname%"
         --export-dpi=600
         --export-pdf="%newname%"
     ]],
     pngargument = [[
         "%oldname%"
         --export-dpi=600
         --export-png="%newname%"
     ]],
 }
 \stopluacode
```

I'll also send a bugfix to the ConTeXt mailing list.